# Non-default constructors in fragments with DatePicker Callback

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-datepicker

There exist answers on how to avoid this problem by creating `newInstance` method, however as i am sending a `listener` as a parameter and that i cannot send that `listener` through `Bundle` how can i solve this issue?

Here i have an `interface` that **listens to calendar change**:

```
    public interface DateChangeListener {
    public void onDateChanged(Calendar calendar);
    }
```

Here i am opening `DatePicker DialogFragment` from `Fragment`:

**(for clarity: There is a `Fragment` where i create a `Custom AlertDialog` on some button click, then inside that `Dialog` i open this `DialogFragment(mDatePicker)` which initializes `DatePickerFragment`)**

```
DialogFragment mDatePicker = new DatePickerFragment(new DateChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onDateChanged(Calendar calendar) {
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //Set date
    filtersInputEditText.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/").append(month + 1).append("/").append(year));
}
```

And here is `DialogFragment` created:

```
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private DateChangeListener mListener;

    public DatePickerFragment(DateChangeListener mListener){
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, day);

        if(mListener != null)
            mListener.onDateChanged(calendar);
    }
}
```

The code runs well, but when i try to make a `signed apk` it warns me with `non-default constructor` message. How can i use `newInstance` strategy here, or should i change the way i am implementing this feature?

notice also that i am forcing app to keep `orientation` as `landscape` in `Manifest`, `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Comment: Orientation is not the only way to make an `Activity/Fragment` recreate. A configuration change, like when the user changes their font, will also make the Activity/Fragment recreate.

Answer (score 2):

1. Fragment should have Empty constructor If you don't want to have issues with configurations changed such as screen rotation or low memory case. When configurations changed, Android will re-create Fragment using empty constructor automatically.
2. For your case. DateChangeListener should be implemented by

   - Host Activity - If you Open DatePickerFragment from Activity
   - TargetFragment (by setting setTargetFragment from Fragment) - If you open DatePickerFragment from Fragment (like parent fragment)
3. From DatePickerFragment, you can access DateChangeListener by casting as below:

   - (DateChangeListener)this.getActivity() ----> If the host activity implement DateChangeListener
   - (DateChangeListener)this.getTargetFragment() ---> If the parent fragment (setTargetFragment) implement DateChangeListener

Comment: this is not only for screen rotation. there are a lot of cases when fragment with non-default constructor will fail miserably.

Comment: by saying `DateChangeListener should be implemented by Target Fragment (as i am coming from Fragment)` what do you actually mean? `DateChangeListener` is an `interface` where it doesnt takes `implements`

Comment: Not only it must have empty, more importantly it must not have non-empty constructors. They don't make any sense in a Fragment.

Comment: @hrskrs: Let say DatePickerFragment open from Fragment1 so Fragment1 must implement DateChangeListener interface and we have to do: datePickerFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0) when we create datePickerFragment instance.

Comment: @LocHa the thing is that i have an `AlertDialog` inside a `Fragment`. Firstly the `AlertDialog` is opened and then in there i create `datePickerFragment`

Comment: What if the user changes their font? Will the `Fragment` be recreated then? That is a configuration change...

Comment: @LocHa the application process may be killed, but the Activity (and Fragment) stack is retained. In this case, the Android has to recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a Bus (like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)). When using an interface, you are coupling the class that implements the interface with the one that uses said interface. Using a Bus avoids this since subscribers do not know where events are coming from.

The reason why you get the warning is because the framework may need to recreate your `Fragment` (e.g. when you rotate the screen). When it does so, the `FragmentManager` will call the `Fragment`'s default constructor, hence the non-default constructor will not be called.